# Closure Compiler Externs - arguments - WARNING - Bad type annotation. type not recognized due to syntax error

Tags: arguments, google-closure-compiler

I am getting the following warning:

```
js/lib/pixi-externs.js:848: WARNING - Bad type annotation. type not recognized due to syntax error
* @param {Array.|Array.|...PIXI.Point|...number} points
                            ^
```

Here is the complete line in externs file, related to the above warning:

```
* @param {Array.<PIXI.Point>|Array.<number>|...PIXI.Point|...number} points
```

What am I doing wrong here?
Should `...PIXI.Point` and `...number` be wrapped in `(` `)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ellipsis operator applies to the entire parameter - not a particular type:

```
@param {...(Array<PIXI.Point>|Array<number>|PIXI.Point|number)} points
```